# Lazy Loading Folder in angular 2

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

[image]I am currently using angular version RC-1

can you please explain me how to implement a lazy loading in angular with an example with in the guide lines https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#sts=Lazy%20Loaded%20Folders

it would be very useful to implement in my project

**Prefix Lazy Loaded Folders with +** need a example for this also

explicit I need to load my angular 2 components only on demand

**app.component.ts**

```
  import {Component, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked, OnInit, OnDestroy, DoCheck, Input, Output, SimpleChange,
    EventEmitter, ContentChild, ContentChildren, Renderer, IterableDiffers, Query, QueryList, TemplateRef,
    RouteConfig, Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
    Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, Headers,
    APIServiceHelper
    , APIServiceConstants
    , Header
    , Footer
    , LeftNavigation
    , sample
    , AsyncRoute
} from "./index";
declare var $;
declare function initiateSessionTimeOut(minutes);
declare var System: any;
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Header, Footer, LeftNavigation],
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, APIServiceHelper, APIServiceConstants],
    host: {
        '(document:click)': 'onClick($event)',
    }
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/sample', name: 'sample', component: sample, useAsDefault: true },
    new AsyncRoute({
        path: '/sample',
        loader: () => System.import('./app/sample/sample.component').then(m => m.sample),
        name: 'sample'
    }),
    new AsyncRoute({
        path: '/sample1',
        loader: () => System.import('./app/sample1/sample1.component').then(m => m.sample1),
        name: 'sample1'
    }),
    new AsyncRoute({
        path: '/sample2',
        loader: () => System.import('./app/sample2/sample2.component').then(m => m.sample2),
        name: 'sample2'
    }),


])
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for lazy loading concept with the angular 2 then you just have to make some changes in your routes ... You have to make them load only when they are required ...

> ```
> new AsyncRoute({
> path: '/login',
> loader: () => System.import('./dist/login.component').then(m => m.loginComponent),
> name: 'Login'   })
> ```

just don't forget to import asyncroute..
that's how concept of lazy loading works with angular 2 :)

further you can check this out at https://www.xplatform.rocks/2016/02/09/angular2-quicky-async-routes/

i hope this is what u were looking for :)

Comment: i have followed the above steps but all components js are loading even if route through async route

Comment: can u show me your file where u have defined your routes...? because i am doing the same and this is working pretty fine

Comment: just start again ur npm i.e. npm start .... your code looks correct,it should have changed... n tell me if it still doesn't works

Comment: still it not works please have a loook at screen shot on page load only it is loading every thing

Comment: just check your network tab when u load any page .... if a call is being sent to other components.js file or not ??? lazy loading stops that call... but your files that are being loaded should not be loaded :|

Comment: that's great :) but why was this not working before ??

Comment: i have exported all the component in index.ts file so it was downloading

Answer (score 1):

The bad news is with rc1 you won't be able "load my angular 2 components only on demand"

The good news is with ng2 rc5, you can do this now by ng2 team introducing back "module" just like angularJs 1.
So, first module your project as:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, routing ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then load on demand:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'; 
 const routes: Routes= [{path: 'welcome', loadChildren: 'app/screens/welcome.module'}];
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

here: loadChildren: 'app/screens/welcome.module'  is ts file app/screens/welcome.module.ts

For more detail example, checked this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/nm5m7N?p=preview